# apt: could not find libjava.so

Tags: 16.04, apt, java

I have Ubuntu 16.04. Running `apt` gives

```
Error: could not find libjava.so
Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.
```

Java seems to work fine otherwise. `apt-get` works as well.

```
$ locate libjava.so
/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
```

How could I further diagnose the problem?

**EDIT:** `type apt` returned

```
apt is /usr/local/bin/apt
apt is /usr/bin/apt
```

The second one, `/usr/bin/apt`, works fine.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/apt
apt: /usr/bin/apt
$ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/apt
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/apt
```

So I guess I can just remove `/usr/local/bin/apt`?

Comment: Are you saying just running the `apt` command gives those errors?

Comment: Yes, just running `apt`, as well as e.g `apt autoremove` or any other command I've tried.

Comment: What does `type -a apt` return? ([Edit] your post to include the output.)

Comment: Edited. Problem solved by now, although not sure how it came to be.

Comment: Did you install anything from source recently?

Comment: Not that I remember. But I haven't used `apt` in a while, so the problematic binary could have been there for a while.

Comment: use `ls -l` to see the date/time of the suspect file (`/usr/local/bin/apt`). Use `dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/apt` to see if it came from a package, `file /usr/local/bin/apt` to see what kind of file it is. Has your system been hacked?

Comment: @waltinator apparently this APT could be the Java Annotation Preprocessing Tool (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5032716/2072269), so probably not a case of hacking

Comment: `file` says "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped".

Comment: I used to have JRockit JVM installed from source; maybe the  Annotation Preprocessing Tool was a leftover from that.